# expect script not working in cron but runs successfully in terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, expect

Here is my expect script named as script.exp which runs successfully when executed from terminal. But it doesn't run when scheduling through cronjob.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ./sql_backup.sh
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Enter password: "
send -- "pass123\r"
expect eof
```

my bash script named as sql_backup.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /home/user1/mysql/mysql-bkp.sql
```

and my cronjob is:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/expect -f /home/user1/script.exp
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69793254/7552 ? Please don't ask the same question in different places.

Answer (score 2):

Jobs run through `cron` aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Also note the CWD for cron is `/`, so `./script.sh` is wrong.